# Python Cubes OLAP framework with hierarchies

Tags: python, olap, olap-cube, cubes

So, here we have models (django models) for some parameters value in some country,
divided by subjects(like central subject, west subject and etc.)
and administrative units(regions of subjects. Like Moscow region  of Central Subject in Russia).

```
class Years(models.Model):
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()


class Geography(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    subject_id = models.UUIDField(null=True)
    subject_label = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    administrative_unit_id = models.UUIDField(null=True)
    administrative_unit_label = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)


class Param(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=5)


class Fact(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey(Years)
    geography = models.ForeignKey(Geography)
    param = models.ForeignKey(Param)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=5, null=True)
```

Each parameter value has there dimensions :
year, geography(subject OR administrative unit. But id only for geography), and param type/code/name.

So in models.json we can see what Geography has levels:
subjects consists of administrative units, but each subject has his own values of parameters for year.
(this also true for administrative units).

models.js

```
{
    "dimensions": [
      {
        "name": "cubes_viewer_years",
        "levels": [
          {
            "name": "cubes_viewer_years",
            "label_attribute": "year",
            "attributes": [ "id", "year"],
            "info": { "cv-datefilter": true}
          }
        ]
      },
        {
            "name": "cubes_viewer_param",
            "levels": [
                {
                    "name" : "param",
                    "attributes": ["id", "codename", "name"],
                    "label_attribute": "name"
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            "name": "cubes_viewer_geography",
            "levels": [
                {
                    "name": "subject",
                    "attributes": [ "subject_id", "subject_label"],
                    "key": "subject_id",
                    "label_attribute": "subject_label"
                },
                {
                    "name": "administrative_unit",
                    "attributes":
                    [ "administrative_unit_id", "administrative_unit_label"],
                    "key": "administrative_unit_id",
                    "label_attribute": "administrative_unit_label"
                }
            ]
        }

    ],
    "cubes": [
      {
        "name": "cubes_viewer_fact",
        "label": "Индикаторы",
        "measures": [{"name": "value", "aggregates": ["sum", "avg", "max", "min"]}],
        "dimensions": ["cubes_viewer_years", "cubes_viewer_param", "cubes_viewer_geography"],
        "joins": [
          {"master": "cubes_viewer_fact.year_id", "detail": "cubes_viewer_years.id"},
          {"master": "cubes_viewer_fact.param_id", "detail": "cubes_viewer_param.id"},
          {"master": "cubes_viewer_fact.geography_id", "detail": "cubes_viewer_geography.id"}
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

**Problem:**
If i want to drilldown by administrative unit - everything works fine
 (EXCEPT values for every subject named like SUBJECT_NAME / , not SUBJECT_NAME / ADMINISTRATIVE_UNIT_NAME. (in filter panel of cubes viewer)).
And everything filtered fine.

BUT, if i want to drilldown by subject - the filter panel of cubes viewer allow to select too many values of Subject names - like one subject like (not unique) for every administrative unit name.

This is not right.
How to build cube models hierarchy right for that kind of data hierarchy.
Or i can separate Geography tables. Is so - how to build right cube models hierarchy for that ?

May be i miss something in documentation, but i tried to use example from cubes viewer webvisits app - and description above is that i got...

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

You could separate Geography into two tables (in that case you can add an entry to your `join` that defines how to join those tables).

But you shouldn't need to do that. Cubes can handle this, and your joins and dimension config seems right to me.

Perhaps you are missing `mappings`:

```
"mappings": {
    "cubes_viewer_geography.subject_id": "cubes_viewer_geography.subject_id",
    "cubes_viewer_geography.subject_label": "cubes_viewer_geography.subject_label",
    "cubes_viewer_geography.administrative_unit_id": "cubes_viewer_geography.administrative_unit_id",
    "cubes_viewer_geography.administrative_unit_label": "cubes_viewer_geography.administrative_unit_label"
}
```